# SSH to raspberrypi hangs after about 30 seconds, unless the raspberrypi is being pinged

Tags: ssh, pi-1

### Symptoms

ssh connection to raspberrypi hangs after rougly 30 seconds, unless I ping the raspberrypi.

The raspberry pi is at `raspberrypi.lan`

I have a script `~/troubleshoot.sh`

```
#! /bin/bash
uptime
free
while :; do
    sleep 1; echo $SECONDS
done
```

I can run this while logged into `raspberrypi.lan` via ssh, or run it remotely from my laptop:

```
ssh raspberrypi ./troubleshoot.sh
 19:34:35 up 11 days, 23:05,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.00
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          439596       73516      112016         160      254064      308364
Swap:         102396      101940         456
1
2
3

... 4, 5, 6 etc ...

27
28
29
```

This will hang when `$SECONDS` is around 30 ... it might be as low as 28, or as high as 34. When run remotely, I have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to terminate.

If I'm logged into `raspberrypi.lan` via ssh, I see the same behavior, but I have to use <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>~</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd>.

... so something is causing the ssh session to hang.

If I open a separate terminal window on my laptop and run

```
ping raspberrypi.lan
```

the ssh session will not hang; I can stay logged on indefinitely.

### History

I had an old version of Raspbian running on the pi -- so old that the repositories were well out of date. `ssh` worked under that version. I loaded Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) on a new SD card and enabled ssh, then noticed that my ssh sessions were freezing after a short period of time.

### Environment

- Hardware: Raspberry Pi 1B
- OS/Distro Version: Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
- Network: Wired, dual stack (ipv4, ipv6)

  $ host raspberrypi.lan
  raspberrypi.lan has address 192.168.12.189
  raspberrypi.lan has IPv6 address 2607:fb90:2c88:43b2:b04c:80cb:0:167
- IP addresses are dynamic on both IPV4 and IPV6
- sshd: `OpenSSH_8.4p1 Raspbian-5+deb11u1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022`
- `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

  `Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/.conf
  Host *
  SendEnv LANG LC_
  HashKnownHosts yes
  GSSAPIAuthentication yes`
- no files in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/`
- `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` is identical to that of another server that I have no issues logging in to.
- `~/.ssh/config` on laptop:

  `Host raspberrypi
  User barton
  Hostname raspberrypi.lan
  ServerAliveInterval=60
  ServerAliveCountMax=10`

## What I've tried so far

- `~/troubleshoot.sh` shows uptime -- this is now over 12 days. This rules out power issues causing the pi to reboot.
- `raspberrypi.lan` is constantly pingable -- this isn't a network connectivity issue.
- All ip addresses on the lan are dynamic; this isn't an IP address conflict.
- I used the `check.sh` script posted by @goldilocks in his reply to
  [Raspberry pi always stops responding to SSH after some hours powered](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/29076/28384) to determine that `sshd` is not dying.
- Tried adding

  `ServerAliveInterval 60
  ServerAliveCountMax 10`

  to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and restarting sshd. No change.
- Looked in `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/messages` for ssh errors. Didn't see anything.
- Tried connecting using `ssh -v -v -v raspeberrypi.lan` didn't see anything unusual (much as I suspected, since I was connecting correctly).
- Ran `journalctl -u ssh` -- I probably need to go a bit farther down this path, because I was tired when I tried it, and didn't think to `nohup` it and redirect to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a clue/work-around while writing up the question.

The ping that was keeping things alive was returning ipv6 packets:

```
$ ping raspberrypi.lan
PING raspberrypi.lan(raspberrypi.lan (2607:fb90:2c88:43b2:b04c:80cb:0:167)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from raspberrypi.lan (2607:fb90:2c88:43b2:b04c:80cb:0:167): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=5.61 ms
64 bytes from raspberrypi.lan (2607:fb90:2c88:43b2:b04c:80cb:0:167): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=11.4 ms
64 bytes from raspberrypi.lan (2607:fb90:2c88:43b2:b04c:80cb:0:167): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=67.9 ms
64 bytes from raspberrypi.lan (2607:fb90:2c88:43b2:b04c:80cb:0:167): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=78.5 ms
...
```

I tried adding `AddressFamily=inet6` to ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host raspberrypi
    User barton
    Hostname raspberrypi.lan
    ServerAliveInterval=60
    ServerAliveCountMax=10
    AddressFamily=inet6
```

... this didn't work, but when I changed it to `AddressFamily=inet` -- forcing traffic over IPV4 -- I was able to connect without pinging raspberrypi.lan.

I think that the ipv6 network is timing out somehow, and the ping is keeping it alive, but the ipv4 network is staying alive. It's still a mystery, but at least I have a workaround that doesn't involve setting up a ping in parallel to my ssh session.